# iframe won't scroll in Firefox 17

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom

After upgrading Firefox to 17 iframe scrolling stopped working in my web application. I've read that something has changed with mouse wheel event in the latest Firefox ( https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Mouse_Wheel_Scrolling ) but I don't know why it would prevent my iframe from scrolling. Maybe it's because I'm creating this iframe automatically with JavaScript. Scrolling works in the latest version of Chrome and older versions of Firefox.

**jQuery :**

```
  var iframe = $(document.createElement("iframe")).attr("src", $(this).attr("href")+"&without_js=1")
      .css({"border": "0", "width": "100%", "height": ($(window).height() - 100 - 100)+"px", "overflow":"scroll"})
      .attr("id", "zaplanowanie_przegladu_frame").attr("name", "table_frame").hide().appendTo($("body"));
```

Comment: try removing `overflow:scroll` because it shouldn't do anything useful AFAIK. If it breaks iframes in new FF it deserves a bug report

Comment: And if this doesn't help - the problem probably is inside the iframe, not the iframe itself.

Comment: So you're creating an iframe within an iframe?

Comment: Used your exact code (with a static URL) to create an iframe in jsfiddle and there are no problems. It's worth pointing out that adding overflow: scroll (or overflow: anything, for that matter) to the iframe with CSS does nothing - scrolling of the iframe is controlled by the scrolling attribute, not CSS. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am experiencing a similar issue. I am placing scrolling on the body attribute of the iframe though. It was working prior to FF17. I will try to pull together a lowest common denominator reproduction of the bug.

I found someone reporting a similar issue on the mozilla support site:
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942843

Comment: You think it is a bug? Maybe this behaviour is intetded becouse it's standand of new HTML? I'm not sure...

Comment: Yes. I do think it is a bug. I have confirmed that this was not the case as of FF16. Others are reporting this as well. http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942843

Comment: Here is a similar bug report on JQuery's site: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12951 ... The proposed temporary workaround (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12846) is to add an "overflow:auto !important;" in the CSS. That will not work in my situation, but might work in yours.

Comment: overflow:auto !important;" working for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: I take that back... overflow:auto !important; worked perfectly in my case. Not a great solution, but a good work around until FireFox fixes this issue.