# Firefox 17 scrolling bug

Tags: css, firefox, iframe

I have a div with an overflow on it to allow a calendar to scroll. But in FF 17 it seems to have a rendering issue that shows up if you scroll upwards. The top of the page just gets repeated inside (image attached). It corrects itself after a few seconds.

A few boards on the web have suggested switching this on in about:config (gfx.direct2d.force-enabled
layers.acceleration.force-enabled
webgl.force-enabled) which does fix the issue, but isn't really a viable option for customers using the web app.

This question here [iframe won't scroll in Firefox 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687843/iframe-wont-scroll-in-firefox-17) seems to be having issues with not scrolling at all, so close but not quite.

[image: see image]

Has anyone else come up against this or have an idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I've only seen this behavior when Flash is involved, and it wasn't unique to FF17. Not sure if that's helpful information or not...

Comment: Seems that you can propose a bug report at [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

Comment: Are you possibly using some CSS3 transitions on any elements inside the iframe code? Might be worth trying to disable them.

Comment: hi! i would propose a bug report. to me it seems as if firefox has scrolling issues since version 15 on. if you want an example, have a look at a very large panorama foto on my page: http://www.bergliste.at/bild-246-1-41-YES.html - with all browsers it is possible to horizontally scroll the div, but since fx15 the image disappears during scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, no CSS3 transitions used anywhere in the app, submitting a bug report now and I'll update this question when I get more info.

Comment: same problem here, no solution so far

Comment: fixed the problem for me, but still not sure what's going on: only had this behaviour after animating some element using css transitions. switching the element's z-index from 1 to 0 after the animation completed solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with your video card and Firefox's hardware acceleration settings.  I would go to **Tools -> Options** then under the **Advanced** panel, **General** tab, look for this region:

[image]

Try toggling those on or off and see if that helps.

Cheers!